# How to find $\sigma$-algebra for given that a function $f:X\to Y$ is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X=\{1,a,b,c\}$, $Y=\{2,A,BC\}$ be two sets, and $f:X\to Y$  be a function such that: $f(1)=2$, $f(a)=A$, and $f(b)=f(c)=BC$. Choosing $\mathcal{G}=\{\underbrace{\{2\}}_{\textrm{set~}G_1}, \underbrace{\{2,BC\}}_{\textrm{set~}G_2}\}$, we then have 
\begin{align}
%\displaybreak
\sigma(\mathcal{G}) &=
\left\{
  \begin{array}{c}
    Y, \varnothing, \\
    G_1, G_2, G_1^c, G_2^c \\
    G_1\cup G_2, (G_1\cup G_2)^c
  \end{array}
\right\}
\equiv
\left\{
  \begin{array}{c}
    \{2, A, BC\}, \varnothing, \\
    \{2\},  \{2, BC\}, \{A, BC\}, \{A\}
  \end{array}
\right\}.
\end{align}

I now present my problem below:

- Consider 2 measurable spaces $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(Y,\sigma(\mathcal{G}))$.
- By definition of **measurable function**, the function $f$ is said to be measurable if $f^{-1}(G_1)\in\mathcal{A}$ and $f^{-1}(G_2)\in\mathcal{A}$ as well.

**Question 1:** How to find $f^{-1}(G_1)$ and $f^{-1}(G_2)$? Are they sets?

**Question 2:** How can we find a relevant $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ that makes $f$ be measurable? Can anyone give me an exact solution please!?

Regards,

Comment: If I understood well, for **question 2** you may, in general, just take the pre-image $\sigma$-algebra, induced by the $\sigma$-algebra in the codomain of $f$. It is a routine calculation to see that in fact it defines a $\sigma$-algebra on the domain, keep in mind the good behavior of pre-images.

Comment: For your reference, see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Pre-Image_Sigma-Algebra/Domain

Comment: Hi @Alufat, thank for your consideration. Could you please give me an exact solution? For example, I can not find what is $f^{-1}(G_2)$, I am wonder whether or not $f^{-1}(G_2) = \{\{f^{-1}(2)\}, f^{-1}(BC)\} = \{1,b,c\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small correction: you should have $\{2, A\}$ and $\{BC\}$ in the $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$. Do you see why?

Question 1: Yes, they're subsets of $X$. We define $f^{-1}(G_i)$ to be the set of all of the elements in $X$ that get mapped to $G_i$ by $f$. This is the preimage of $G_i$ in $X$. So just collect all of the elements which get mapped to $G_i$.

Question 2: To make this map measurable, we have to make sure that $f^{-1}(G_i)$ lives in the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. There's an easy way to create a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ which includes these sets. Hint: you've already done this once to create a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$.

If you take this $\sigma$-algebra, generated by the $f^{-1}(G_i)$s, then $f$ will be measurable.

Note that ordinarily we'd have to take the $\sigma$-algebra of the preimages of everything in $Y$'s $\sigma$-algebra. But because the algebra on $Y$ is generated by the $G_i$s, it's enough to let the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ be generated by the preimages of these two sets. In other words, it's enough to guarantee measurability of $f$ on the generators of $Y$'s algebra. That's just because taking preimages commutes with taking intersections, unions, complements, etc.

Comment: Hi @Josh Keneda, $B$ and $C$ is coupled with each other, I wrote $BC$ because $f(b)=BC$ and $f(c)=BC$. In other words, we can replace $BC$ with $M$, for example. Maybe, $BC$ is making confusion. Anyway, many thanks to you for answering Q1 and Q2. But could you please give me an exact solution. It is hard for me to imagine the content of the answers. Best!

Comment: Hi @Josh, I am wonder whether or not $f^{-1}(G_2) = \{\{f^{-1}(2)\}, f^{-1}(BC)\} = \{1,b,c\}$?

Comment: Hey pej. I've corrected the typo in my correction, but the comment still stands. You're missing sets in your algebra on $Y$.

Comment: And you're right about the preimage of $G_2$. It's just all of the elements in $X$ which land in $G_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @Josh Keneda,
I now correct $\sigma(\mathcal{G})$ in the last post as follows:
\begin{align}
\sigma(\mathcal{G}) &=
\left\{
  \begin{array}{c}
    \{2, A, BC\}, \{\varnothing\}, \\
    \{2\},  \{2, BC\}, \{A, BC\}, \{A\}, \{2, A\}, \{BC\}
  \end{array}
\right\}.
\end{align}

The answer to Q1 is provided by @Josh

For Q2, let $\mathcal{K}=\{f^{-1}(G_1), f^{-1}(G_2)\}$ be a collection of sets $f^{-1}(G_1)$ and $f^{-1}(G_2)$. So can I find $\mathcal{A}$ by forming $\mathcal{A}=\sigma\left(\mathcal{K}\right)$?